# Bessel Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I am doing an exercise which asks for the concentration distribution of a given bacteria. After several computations I reached the following differential equation:

$$x^2y''-xy'+(1+x^2)y=0$$

which seem to be solved with Bessel but I have no idea how to do it. Could you help me please??

Comment: It's very technical to deal with this guy. I'd just take a look at the wiki or use computers to deal with numerics. You won't find a solution in a form that is particularly "nice"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting $y(x)=x\,u(x)$,

$$y'=xu'+u,\\
y''=xu''+2u'.$$

Substituting into the ODE $x^2y'-xy'+(1+x^2)y=0$,

$$x^3u''+2x^2u'-x^2u'-xu+(1+x^2)xu=0,\\
\implies x^3u''+x^2u'+x^3u=0,\\
\implies x^2u''+xu'+x^2u=0.$$

This is the $0$-th order [Bessel ODE](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html), and so has general solution

$$u(x)=c_1J_0(x)+c_2Y_0(x).$$

Then the general solution to the original ODE is

$$y(x)=c_1xJ_0(x)+c_2xY_0(x).$$